# Conditional Cross tabulation in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tidyr, expss

Looking for the quickest way to achieve below task using "expss" package.

With a great package of "expss", we can easily do cross tabulation (which has other advantage and useful functions for cross-tabulations.), we can cross-tabulate multiple variables easily like below.

```
 #install.packages("expss")

 library("expss")
 data(mtcars)


  var1 <- "vs, am, gear, carb"
  var_names = trimws(unlist(strsplit(var1, split = ","))) 


  mtcars %>%
    tab_prepend_values %>%
    tab_cols(total(), ..[(var_names)]) %>%
    tab_cells(cyl) %>%
    tab_stat_cpct() %>%
    tab_pivot()
```

Above gives an output as: (column %)

```
                      #Total    vs          am          gear            carb                        
                                0     1     0     1     3     4   5     1   2    3   4    6    8 

  cyl             4    34.4   5.6  71.4  15.8  61.5   6.7  66.7  40  71.4  60                    
                  6    21.9  16.7  28.6  21.1  23.1  13.3  33.3  20  28.6           40  100      
                  8    43.8  77.8        63.2  15.4  80.0        40        40  100  60       100 
       #Total cases    32.0  18.0  14.0  19.0  13.0  15.0  12.0   5   7.0  10    3  10    1    1
```

However, looking for an approach to create a table like below:

```
 CYL    |  VS = 0   |  AM = 1   |   Gear = 4 or Gear = 5    |  Carb (All)
   4        5.56        61.54               58.82                34.38
   6        16.67       23.08               29.41                21.88
   8        77.78       15.38               11.76                43.75

Total(col%) 100.00      100.00              100.00               100.00
```

Though i can achive this using dplyr and join functions but that is too complex incase we have to pass variables in runtime or dynamically.

Any help will be appriciable. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

1) Making a function which can create proportion out of the sum.

```
myprop_tbl <- function(x){
    return(round(x*100/sum(x),2))
}
```

2) Using purrr's map, applying the function on your data frame and then binding the result.

```
library(tidyverse)
tab <- mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise(vs_sum = sum(vs==0), am_sum = sum(am==1), 
              gear_sum = sum(gear == 4|gear==5), carb_sum= n())

finaltab <- bind_cols(tab[,1],map_df(tab[,2:length(tab)], myprop_tbl))
```

**Output**:

```
# * cyl vs_sum am_sum gear_sum carb_sum
#  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1  4.00   5.56   61.5     58.8     34.4
#2  6.00  16.7    23.1     29.4     21.9
#3  8.00  77.8    15.4     11.8     43.8**
```

## EDIT:

After had a discussion with OP, it seems he also wanted to pass string of functions,

I am using here a package `seplyr`

```
tab <- mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise_se(c("vs_sum = sum(vs==0)",
              "am_sum = sum(am==1)",
              "gear_sum = sum(gear == 4|gear==5)", 
              "carb_sum = n()"))
```

It works also, but weired names you will get, to fix that you can do this:

This works perfectly as original answer which I have posted:

```
tab <- mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise_se(c("vs_sum" := "sum(vs==0)",
              "am_sum" := "sum(am==1)",
              "gear_sum" := "sum(gear == 4|gear==5)", 
              "carb_sum" := "n()"))
```

You may read this here @ this [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/programming-with-dplyr-by-using-dplyr/)

Comment: i really like the way you achieve this using tidyverse, is there any way by which we can pass "summarise(vs_sum = sum(vs==0), am_sum = sum(am==1), 
              gear_sum = sum(gear == 4|gear==5), carb_sum= n())" as an string in summarise function?

Comment: @ayush, we can pass quoted variables, but never saw passing string of function, I am sure that this is achievable , but I also don't know.

Comment: Yeah, i do understand... thanks a lot... will really appreciate if you can share the same if you find the same in future... have a nice day!

Comment: Can achieve for single variable information like below:
D_string <- "vs_sum = sum(vs==0)"

tab1 <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise_(D_string) however for multiple variable it creates a problem...D_string <- "vs_sum = sum(vs==0), am_sum = sum(am==1)"

Comment: @ayush,Thanks !!! For multiple statement  if you use `eval` and `parse`, you can achieve this, `tab <- mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise(eval(parse(text="vs_sum = sum(vs==0)")), 
              eval(parse(text="am_sum = sum(am==1)")))`  , but if fails when it finds charcters like pipe(|) or functions

Comment: @ayush, you can do this using a package called `seplyr`, updating my answer

Answer (score 1):

Solution with orginal 'tab_*':

```
library("expss")
data(mtcars)
var_text = "vs_sum = vs==0, am_sum = am==1, gear_sum = gear == 4|gear==5, carb_sum = total(carb)"
var_expr = parse(text = sprintf("data.frame(%s)", var_text)) # parse text string to expression

var_list = calc(mtcars, 1*eval(var_expr)) %>% # caclulate data.frame with zero/one columns
    prepend_names() %>% # add names as labels
    mis_val(0) %>% # we don't need columns with FALSE condition
    set_val_lab(c("|" = 1)) # suppress values in table - we don't want to see TRUE/1

mtcars %>%
    tab_prepend_values %>%
    tab_cols(total(), var_list) %>%
    tab_cells(cyl) %>%
    tab_stat_cpct() %>%
    tab_pivot()

 # |     |              | #Total | vs_sum | am_sum | gear_sum | carb_sum  |
 # | --- | ------------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | -------- | --------- |
 # | cyl |            4 |   34.4 |    5.6 |   61.5 |     58.8 |      34.4 |
 # |     |            6 |   21.9 |   16.7 |   23.1 |     29.4 |      21.9 |
 # |     |            8 |   43.8 |   77.8 |   15.4 |     11.8 |      43.8 |
 # |     | #Total cases |   32.0 |   18.0 |   13.0 |     17.0 |      32.0 |
```

Comment: Hi @gregory Demin, while downloading the file from shiny, we are getting table with column header starting with th { text-align: center; }          th {border: 1px solid #DDD} , can you please help