# Expss Passing multiple response set questions in string

Tags: r, expss

I used the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879724/passing-multiple-variable-information-inside-r-functions-using-string-variable) to create a function where I can use any number of variables in tab_cells. It works great until I try to put a multiple response set in the string I get an error `` Error: names not found: 'mdset(`4.2_1` %to% `4.2_13`)', 'mdset(`4.3_1` %to% `4.3_12`)' ``

```
connectionsvars <- "connected_scc, mdset(`4.2_1` %to% `4.2_13`), mdset(`4.3_1` %to% `4.3_12`)"
connectionsvar_names = trimws(unlist(strsplit(connectionsvars, split = ",")))
```

```
bannertable = function(varname, varnametitle) {
  xtab = eval(substitute({
    bannertable <- survey_data1 %>% 
      tab_cols(total(), age_range) %>%     
      tab_cells(eval(..[(varname)])) %>% 
      tab_stat_cpct(total_row_position = c("below"),
                    total_statistic = c("w_cpct"),
                    total_label = "#Total %") %>%       
      tab_pivot()
  })) 
  
  assign(paste0(varnametitle, "Wtable"), bannertable, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  
}

bannertable(varname = connectionsvar_names, "connections")
```

How do I use multiple response sets while being able to use any number of variables in tab_cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make custom function and don't insist on incapsulated your variables in `connectionsvars`, the simplest solution is to use dots as argument:

```
library(expss)
data(mtcars)
banner_table = function(varname_title, ...){
    xtab = eval(substitute({
        mtcars %>% 
            tab_cols(total(), am) %>%     
            tab_cells(...) %>% 
            tab_stat_cpct(total_row_position = c("below"),
                          total_statistic = c("w_cpct"),
                          total_label = "#Total %") %>%       
            tab_pivot()
        
        
    }))
    xtab
}



banner_table("First", vs, cyl)
banner_table("First", mdset(cyl %to% vs), am)
```